# Interpreting concatenation operator with comparator

Tags: verilog

Our professor gave us this skeleton for a case statement, and so far no one is able to understand what it's doing.

```
always@(*)
    begin
        case(state)
            3'b000:{nout, nstate} = (in)?(in=1):(in=0)
       endcase
    end
```

More insight:

This is being implemented as a button debouncer.

nout is the output of the next state: a single bit

nstate is the next state: 3 bits

in is also 1 bit wide

My understanding is that the concatenation operator will append nout to nstate resulting in 4 bits.  (ie: if nout is 1 and nstate is 010, this part of the statement will produce 1010)

On the other side of the equality assignment we have a simple comparator, which upon further inspection, doesn't seem to do anything...

It's basically saying

```
if(in == 1) {
    in = 1;
} else {
    in = 0;
}
```

With that understanding, we're assigning a single bit to nout and nstate?

This understanding doesn't make any sense to me.  I've compared my notes with 2 other classmates whom wrote the exact same thing so I'm thinking either we don't understand the code or there's an error.

Further insight:
Upon researching further, I've found the state diagram appear in multiple places, which makes me fairly confident that this is a common Moore Machine.

[image: Moore FSM]

[image: Moore FSM (2)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope that you did not cut and paste those expressions correctly.

```
3'b000:{nout, nstate} = (in)?(in=1):(in=0);
```

The above statement is a complete mess. Most likely it will fail any linting. It might be ok syntactically, but makes no sense logically and makes such code unreadable and not maintainable. It has to look like the following:

```
3'b000:{nout, nstate} = (in)?(1'b1):(1'b0);
```

The left hand side concat represents a signal with lower 3 bit associated with `nstate`, and upper `n` bits with `nout`. The right hand side ternary operator produces either one bit '1' or 1 bit '0' (actually id does the same int the original expression, because 'in' is 1 bit wide. Verilog will extend the rhs one bit to the size of the lhs and add missing '0's. As a result `nout` will be `0` and `nstate` will be either `3'b000` or `3'b001`, depending on the value of `in`.

Comment: I agree entirely with your first paragraph.

Also with the correction to the ternary operator.

"Verilog will extend...missing '0's" <- I did not realize this and it sheds good insight on what he likely intended!  

Thank you.

Comment: Upon further thinking about the problem, understanding how this is intended to work, I believe this answer sufficient to solve the problem.

Mods feel free to mark 'unanswered' if you see fit!